# Passing two numbers for each visible image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple images with a common class. The user is able to hide or make them visible.

I need to pass two numbers for each visible image. The starting number should be 0 and should be a continues number. This is what I've done so far.

The current output is 0,1,1,2,2,3....

I want the output to be 0,1,2,3,4,5,....

```
$('#passNum').click(function(){
    var curNumber= 0;
    $('.visibeimage:visible').each(function(){
          useNumber(curNumber++);
    });
});
```

Note: the first number should be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass default index parameter in each function instead of you manually iterating

```
$('.visibeimage:visible').each(function(index, value){
      useNumber(index + 1);
});
```

Comment: pass `useNumber(index)`;

Comment: That error in your click function not the each function. Put alert in click function know how many alerts are coming it comes more than one it didn't make sense